# Value of this definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

$f$ is a differentiable function such that $f(f(x)) = x$ for $x ∈ [0, 1]$. And $f(0) = 1$.
What is the value of $\int_0^1{(x − f(x))^{2016}}dx$ ?

I have noticed that one solution of $f$ is $f(x) = 1-x$, then the integral can be easily evaluated. Can it be done without assuming $f(x) = 1-x$?

Comment: This looks like a contest problem. If so, there is a tag for that, and it could be a good gesture to give the reference.